# How to ping a server url/port?

Tags: python, tcp, ip, ping

How do I ping a server via the url / port in python, and receive the response in ms (milliseconds)?
I'm beating my head, I've used `tcping`, and I'm studying sockets, but it doesn't seem so simple, any tips?

`pings_ookla_script_root-OK.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import os
import sys
import pings

p = pings.Ping(quiet=False)
port = 8080

response = p.ping('google.com', times=4)
print(response)
```

Output:

```
47 bytes from 142.250.78.206: icmp_seq=0 ttl=114 time=11.326 ms
47 bytes from 142.250.78.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=11.059 ms
47 bytes from 142.250.78.206: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=10.793 ms
47 bytes from 142.250.78.206: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=11.213 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 10.793/11.098/11.326 ms
{'max_rtt': 11.325597763061523, 'min_rtt': 10.793447494506836, 'avg_rtt': 11.09778881072998, 'packet_lost': None, 'ret_code': 0, 'packet_size': 47, 'timeout               ': 1000, 'dest': 'google.com', 'dest_ip': '142.250.78.206'}
```

Comment: You don't `ping` a *port*, you ping a *host*. Ping is a protocol defined on Internet layer, rather than on the Transport layer. See [Internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)

Comment: I think the `pings` module already returns the response in milliseconds. It looks like it is in `response.avg_rtt`. To get rid of the other output do `p = pings.Ping(quiet=True)` so you better see what is returned and what not.

Comment: OK! But how do I know my server's response time? Is there any other way? I've tried tcping and I couldn't evolve, any tips?

Comment: If your server is running at home, you have to ask some friends to ping it. Otherwise you can't see how fast it is. Best would be if you have friends from all over the world pinging your server. You also could use a v-server or anything that can run the ping command from somewhere else via remote connection. On the other hand, nowadays the upload speed is similar to the download speed. If you ping something on the web like google, you pretty much got the speed of your server - 11 milliseconds currently. But clients on other continents might be much worse. It depends on the client location.

Comment: Hi areap-enap, Thank you for the tips
but it is a web server that is only accessible via the port, eg jardel.com:8080, and I wanted to know its response time.
I get this answer through zabbix, but I wanted to find out via python script

Answer (score 0):

You can't ping ports, as Ping is using ICMP which doesn't have the concept of ports. Ports belong to the transport layer protocols like TCP and UDP.

If you want do web server test that is only accessible via the port,you can use **module tcp_latency**

> tcp-latency provides an easy way to measure latency using TCP.
> Inspired by other similar tools, tcp-latency comes from the need of running network diagnosis/troubleshooting tasks with Python on serverless infrastructure (as many providers don't include ping/ICMP support) but should work too in any other environment with Python>=36.
> Features
> Runs as a command-line tool or inside your code as a module.
> Custom parameters for a port, runs, timeout and wait time between runs.
> IPv4 (e.g 52.26.14.11) and domain (e.g google.com) host support.
> Human readable output when running as a command-line tool.
> No external dependencies.
> Small and extensible.

```
pip3 install tcp_latency
python3
```

now you are in python env.

```
>>> from tcp_latency import measure_latency
>>> measure_latency(host='google.com')
[34.57]
>>> measure_latency(host='52.26.14.11', port=80, runs=10, timeout=2.5)
[433.82, 409.21, 409.25, 307.09, 306.64, 409.45, 306.58, 306.93, 409.25, 409.26]
```

### Other sussgetion:

If you try to do ping test everywhere. I suggest using mature tools.
Ping test result includes national and international client ping result.
By googling "ping test around the world", the top ranking includes "https://tools.keycdn.com/ping","https://www.dotcom-tools.com/ping-test" and etc.